# cumulative distribution plots python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am doing a project using python where I have two arrays of data. Let's call them *pc* and *pnc*. I am required to plot a cumulative distribution of both of these on the same graph. For *pc* it is supposed to be a less than plot i.e. at (x,y), y points in *pc* must have value less than x. For *pnc* it is to be a more than plot i.e. at (x,y), y points in *pnc* must have value more than x.

I have tried using histogram function - `pyplot.hist`. Is there a better and easier way to do what i want? Also, it has to be plotted on a logarithmic scale on the x-axis.

Comment: It'd help if you showed your attempts so far - sample input data, desired output etc... Otherwise this reads as a "show me the code" question

Comment: To extend Jon's comment, people are _much_ happier to help you fix the code you have rather than to generate code from scratch.  No matter how buggy and non-functional your code is, show it and explain what a) you expect it to do and b) what it is currently doing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You were close. You should not use `plt.hist` as `numpy.histogram`, that gives you both the values and the bins, than you can plot the cumulative with ease:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some fake data
data = np.random.randn(1000)
# evaluate the histogram
values, base = np.histogram(data, bins=40)
#evaluate the cumulative
cumulative = np.cumsum(values)
# plot the cumulative function
plt.plot(base[:-1], cumulative, c='blue')
#plot the survival function
plt.plot(base[:-1], len(data)-cumulative, c='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, you forgot to include the np before the cumsum as your np.histogram command implies is needed.

Comment: Using a histogram is both unnecessarily heavy and imprecise.

Comment: @EOL but necessary for large arrays else you'll run out of memory.

Comment: Indeed, but I take that this is not the particular case of the question, which is more about how to get the cumulative distribution than to do it in the case of a large array, and approximately.

Comment: This isnt exactly a CDF though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Answer (score 33):

Using histograms is really unnecessarily heavy and imprecise (the binning makes the data fuzzy): you can just sort all the x values: the index of each value is the number of values that are smaller. This shorter and simpler solution looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some fake data:
data = np.random.randn(1000)

sorted_data = np.sort(data)  # Or data.sort(), if data can be modified

# Cumulative counts:
plt.step(sorted_data, np.arange(sorted_data.size))  # From 0 to the number of data points-1
plt.step(sorted_data[::-1], np.arange(sorted_data.size))  # From the number of data points-1 to 0

plt.show()
```

Furthermore, a more appropriate plot style is indeed `plt.step()` instead of `plt.plot()`, since the data is in discrete locations.

The result is:

[image]

You can see that it is **more ragged** than the output of EnricoGiampieri's answer, but this one is the real histogram (instead of being an approximate, fuzzier version of it).

**PS**: As SebastianRaschka noted, the very last point should ideally show the total count (instead of the total count-1). This can be achieved with:

```
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]),
         np.arange(sorted_data.size+1))
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data[::-1], sorted_data[[0]]]),
         np.arange(sorted_data.size+1))
```

There are so many points in `data` that the effect is not visible without a zoom, but the very last point at the total count does matter when the data contains only a few points.

Comment: However for large arrays you want to go with the histogram approach as it doesn't require nearly as much memory. The `plt.step` method gives me a memory error with my 60 million element array.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure whether the problem lies with `plt.step` or with the fact that this exact method uses maybe 3 times the memory of the array, or both…

Comment: I agree: plt.step is probably the more appropriate approach for plotting "counts". One question: wouldn't you have to use `plt.step(sorted_data, np.arange(1, data.size+1))` to get the correct counts?

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: The plotted function is correct as in the answer because the `step()` function plots each data point, but draws lines (steps) by "moving *vertically* first" and then moving vertically to the next point (by default). As a consequence, the first data value is plotted a step that goes from 0 count (where the data point is) to 1 count. You can see this with explicitly with, e.g., `step(arange(4)+10, arange(4), "o")`.

Comment: @EOL Hm, you are right about the starting point, but I find the end-point a little bit weird. E.g., if I would plot something simple like `plt.step([1.1,1.1,1.1,1.3,1.4], [0,1,2,3,4])`, I would expect the line to start at `3` (which is correct in this case), but the last vertical line ends at 4 then. And shouldn't it be 5 since there are 5 data points in my data set?

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: Good point. You are correct. A perfect solution would add this last point. This can be done by duplicating the last abscissa and adding the total count (5) at the last ordinate. I updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your workaround looks definitely nicer than mine :)

Comment: This isnt exactly a CDF though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: Indeed. I changed one word in order to reflect this.

Comment: This is simple and nice, especially accounting for the last point.  It would be even better if it could be extended beneath the lowest value to 0 and above the highest value to 1 (ie you could specify the range over which to plot it)

Answer (score 15):

After conclusive discussion with @EOL, I wanted to post my solution (upper left) using a random Gaussian sample as a summary:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil, floor, sqrt

def pdf(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    """
    Calculates the normal distribution's probability density 
    function (PDF).  

    """
    term1 = 1.0 / ( sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma )
    term2 = np.exp( -0.5 * ( (x-mu)/sigma )**2 )
    return term1 * term2


# Drawing sample date poi
##################################################

# Random Gaussian data (mean=0, stdev=5)
data1 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=5.0, size=30)
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=7.0, size=30)
data1.sort(), data2.sort()

min_val = floor(min(data1+data2))
max_val = ceil(max(data1+data2))

##################################################




fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12,11)

# Cumulative distributions, stepwise:
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.step(np.concatenate([data1, data1[[-1]]]), np.arange(data1.size+1), label='$\mu=0, \sigma=5$')
plt.step(np.concatenate([data2, data2[[-1]]]), np.arange(data2.size+1), label='$\mu=2, \sigma=7$') 

plt.title('30 samples from a random Gaussian distribution (cumulative)')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('X-value')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlim([min_val, max_val])
plt.ylim([0, data1.size+1])
plt.grid()

# Cumulative distributions, smooth:
plt.subplot(2,2,2)

plt.plot(np.concatenate([data1, data1[[-1]]]), np.arange(data1.size+1), label='$\mu=0, \sigma=5$')
plt.plot(np.concatenate([data2, data2[[-1]]]), np.arange(data2.size+1), label='$\mu=2, \sigma=7$') 

plt.title('30 samples from a random Gaussian (cumulative)')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('X-value')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlim([min_val, max_val])
plt.ylim([0, data1.size+1])
plt.grid()


# Probability densities of the sample points function
plt.subplot(2,2,3)

pdf1 = pdf(data1, mu=0, sigma=5)
pdf2 = pdf(data2, mu=2, sigma=7)
plt.plot(data1, pdf1, label='$\mu=0, \sigma=5$')
plt.plot(data2, pdf2, label='$\mu=2, \sigma=7$')

plt.title('30 samples from a random Gaussian')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('X-value')
plt.ylabel('probability density')
plt.xlim([min_val, max_val])
plt.grid()


# Probability density function
plt.subplot(2,2,4)

x = np.arange(min_val, max_val, 0.05)

pdf1 = pdf(x, mu=0, sigma=5)
pdf2 = pdf(x, mu=2, sigma=7)
plt.plot(x, pdf1, label='$\mu=0, \sigma=5$')
plt.plot(x, pdf2, label='$\mu=2, \sigma=7$')

plt.title('PDFs of Gaussian distributions')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('X-value')
plt.ylabel('probability density')
plt.xlim([min_val, max_val])
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

In order to add my own contribution to the community, here I share my function for plotting histograms. This is how I understood the question, plotting the histogram and the cumulative histograme at the same time :

```
def hist(data, bins, title, labels, range = None):
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
  ax = plt.axes()
  plt.ylabel("Proportion")
  values, base, _ = plt.hist( data  , bins = bins, normed=True, alpha = 0.5, color = "green", range = range, label = "Histogram")
  ax_bis = ax.twinx()
  values = np.append(values,0)
  ax_bis.plot( base, np.cumsum(values)/ np.cumsum(values)[-1], color='darkorange', marker='o', linestyle='-', markersize = 1, label = "Cumulative Histogram" )
  plt.xlabel(labels)
  plt.ylabel("Proportion")
  plt.title(title)
  ax_bis.legend();
  ax.legend();
  plt.show()
  return
```

if anyone wonders how it looks like, please take a look (with seaborn activated):

[image]

Also, concerning the double grid (the white lines), I always used to struggle to have nice double grid. Here is an interesting way to circumvent the problem: [How to put grid lines from the secondary axis behind the primary plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615701/how-to-put-grid-lines-from-the-secondary-axis-behind-the-primary-plot)

Comment: if you expect negative values in your array, you probably want to take the absolute... otherwise the cumulative histogram will look off

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to generate this graph is with `seaborn`:

```py
import seaborn as sns  
sns.ecdfplot()
```

Here is the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.ecdfplot.html)