# numpy histogram cumulative density does not sum to 1

Tags: python, numpy

Taking a tip from another thread ([@EnricoGiampieri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408371/cumulative-distribution-plots-python/15419072#15419072) to [cumulative distribution plots python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408371/cumulative-distribution-plots-python)), I wrote:

```
# plot cumulative density function of nearest nbr distances
# evaluate the histogram
values, base = np.histogram(nearest, bins=20, density=1)
#evaluate the cumulative
cumulative = np.cumsum(values)
# plot the cumulative function
plt.plot(base[:-1], cumulative, label='data')
```

I put in the `density=1` from the documentation on `np.histogram`, which says:

> Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen; it is not a probability mass function.

Well, indeed, when plotted, they don't sum to 1.  But, I do not understand the "bins of unity width."  When I set the bins to 1, of course, I get an empty chart; when I set them to the population size, I don't get a sum to 1 (more like 0.2).  When I use the 40 bins suggested, they sum to about .006.

Can anybody give me some guidance?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the area sum to one?

Comment: I would guess yes.  Paul, I am sorry -- my statistics is weak.  I am working from an R example where the y-axis values run from 0 to 1 and the CDF caps out at 1.

Comment: (I would post a screen shot if I knew how.) <-- not allowed to at my level of newness.  Curve caps out at 0.2 but over x-values from 2000-8000, so I believe the area would be one.

Comment: For me when I had bins from `np.arange(0, 1005, 10)` I just had to multiply all by 10. I haven`t checked yet, but seems you just have to multiply density by the difference factor, which is 10 in my occasion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make sure your bins are all width 1. That is:

```
np.all(np.diff(base)==1)
```

To achieve this, you have to manually specify your bins:

```
bins = np.arange(np.floor(nearest.min()),np.ceil(nearest.max()))
values, base = np.histogram(nearest, bins=bins, density=1)
```

And you get:

```
In [18]: np.all(np.diff(base)==1)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: np.sum(values)
Out[19]: 0.99999999999999989
```

Comment: Hooray!  Thank you -- and now the curve more resembles my target.

Comment: From the docs:  `If \`bins\` is an int, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the given range (10, by default)` - so OP's example should work by default, no? Seems like a bug.

Comment: Equal width to each other, but not necessarily width 1.

Comment: Ah, I see, it sums to the bin width, so with equal width bins you can get unity by dividing by `base[1]-base[0]`.

Answer (score 24):

You can simply normalize your `values` variable yourself like so:

`unity_values = values / values.sum()`

A full example would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(size=37)
density, bins = np.histogram(x, normed=True, density=True)
unity_density = density / density.sum()

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, figsize=(8,4))
widths = bins[:-1] - bins[1:]
ax1.bar(bins[1:], density, width=widths)
ax2.bar(bins[1:], density.cumsum(), width=widths)

ax3.bar(bins[1:], unity_density, width=widths)
ax4.bar(bins[1:], unity_density.cumsum(), width=widths)

ax1.set_ylabel('Not normalized')
ax3.set_ylabel('Normalized')
ax3.set_xlabel('PDFs')
ax4.set_xlabel('CDFs')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Paul.  I actually did try dividing through (normalizing) my "nearest" vector some days ago.  Can't remember why I wasn't happy with the outcome.  Probably did it wrong.

Comment: In the line `density, bins = np.histogram(x, normed=True, density=True)`, why are both `normed` and `density` set to `True`? The numpy docs say `normed` is deprecated; I ask because I'm trying to get a normalized cumulative histogram via `numpy histogram`.

Comment: @mikey this answer was written in 2014 before numpy deprecated `normed`. What do you mean by normalized? Some folks mean that the value of the tallest bar should be 1 in a normalized histogram. Others want the area of the bars to sum to 1. I'm pretty sure `density` gets you the latter, and you'll have to compute the former yourself.

Comment: @mikey (the numpy docs explain the density kwarg better than I could, btw)

Comment: @PaulH By normalized, I mean that the area under the curve sums to 1. I asked a [new question about it in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333616/how-to-produce-a-normalized-cumulative-histogram).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the statement

"Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen; it is not a probability mass function. "

means that the output that we are getting is the probability density function for the respective bins,
now since in pdf, the probability between two value say 'a' and 'b' is represented by the area under the pdf curve between the range 'a' and 'b'.
therefore to get the probability value for a respective bin, we have to **multiply the pdf value of that bin by its bin width**, and then the sequence of probabilities obtained can be directly used for calculating the cumulative probabilities(as they are now normalized).

note that the sum of the new calculated probabilities will give 1, which satisfies the fact that the sum of total probability is 1, or in other words, we can say that our probabilities are normalized.

see code below,
here i have use bins of different widths, some are of width 1 and some are of width 2,

```
import numpy as np
import math
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)   # deterministic random data
a = np.hstack((rng.normal(size=1000),
               rng.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=1000))) # 'a' is our distribution of data
mini=math.floor(min(a))
maxi=math.ceil(max(a))
print(mini)
print(maxi)
ar1=np.arange(mini,maxi/2)
ar2=np.arange(math.ceil(maxi/2),maxi+2,2)
ar=np.hstack((ar1,ar2))
print(ar)  # ar is the array of unequal widths, which is used below to generate the bin_edges
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, bins=ar, 
                             density = True)
print(counts)    # the pdf values of respective bin_edges
print(bin_edges) # the corresponding bin_edges
print(np.sum(counts*np.diff(bin_edges)))  #finding total sum of probabilites, equal to 1
print(np.cumsum(counts*np.diff(bin_edges))) #to get the cummulative sum, see the last value, it is 1.
```

Now the reason I think they try to mention by saying that the width of bins should be 1, is might be because of the fact that **if the width of bins is equal to 1, then the value of pdf and probabilities for any bin are equal**, because if we calculate the area under the bin, then we are basically multiplying the 1 with the corresponding pdf of that bin, which is again equal to that pdf value.
so in this case, the value of pdf is equal to the value of the respective bins probabilities and hence already normalized.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution, which makes your bins add up to 1.

Set

```
density = False
```

and instead use weights, like so:

```
weights=np.ones(len(values)) / len(values)
```

I can't explain it properly, but you can read it here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10398/