# Cumulative probability plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I make a plot of this style in python with matplotlib?  [(Cumulative probability plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dQ9z.png) I don't need complete code, mostly just need a place to start and a general idea of what I need to do for it.

Comment: Do you already have the equation describing the trend line or do you want to compute it from the data points? Besides that, ``pyplot.plot(x,y,'-')`` generates you a linear plot and ``pyplot.plot(x,y,'o')`` will generate the markers for the data.

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorials and examples on the Matplotlib web site? One of those might match the kind of plot you want. http://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html and http://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

Comment: All I have is the actual data (the CO2flux values on the y axis). I'm familiar with the basic plotting functions of matplotlib, it's the cumulative probability distribution on the x axis that I need help generating.

Comment: StatsModels Q-Q plot? http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408371/cumulative-distribution-plots-python

Answer (score 1):

A cumulative probability plot is really easy to make:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(1000)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.sort(data),np.linspace(0.0,1.0,len(data)))

plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(X \leq x)$')

plt.show()
```

Note that it can have a strong advantage over a probability density plot as it does not require binning of your data. (Should you be looking for the latter you can check [this code](https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseMPL/blob/master/goosempl/goosempl.py)).

[image]