# Keep matplotlib dual axis gridlines under previously plotted series

Tags: python, matplotlib

Normally, gridlines are "below" all plotted series. But when using `twinx` to create a dual series, the newly added grid lines are added atop previously plotted series. Example ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y9Rowa72_GPo6cdf36aL7gUCOax5vdMF?usp=sharing)):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams.update({'axes.grid': True, 'grid.color': 'gray'})

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 4], 'b': [10, 300, 200]}, index=[1, 2, 3])

ax1 = df.a.plot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df.b.plot(ax=ax2, c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Here's a close-up of the bottom left corner, where you can see that the blue line is under the new (lower) gridline while the red line is on top of it.

[image: close up]

How can I keep the dual-axis gridlines below all plotted data?

Comment: a quick fix would be to rescale the y-axes such that the gridlines lie on top of each other. In that specific example it would be (0,4) and (0,400) or (0,4) and (0,200). An alternative would be to switch the grid off for one axis, but then the gridlines would not line up on both sides

Comment: Note that matplotlib always draws everything belonging to one ax before starting elements belonging to another ax.

Comment: Have a look at this answer regarding twinx and plotting with grid lines on both axes- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55618417

Comment: @warped aligning the axes doesn't work, the gridlines still write over the first series.