# Matplotlib - cumulative density plot with Y-axis as cumulative fraction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can make a cumulative density plot ([cumulative distribution plots python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408371/cumulative-distribution-plots-python)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some fake data:
data = np.random.randn(1000)

sorted_data = np.sort(data)  # Or data.sort(), if data can be modified

# Cumulative counts:
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]),
         np.arange(sorted_data.size+1))

plt.show()
```

However, I would like the Y-axis to be represented as the cumulative fraction. Some value between 0 and 1. How can I scale my Y-axis to do this?

**Solution**

See answer by Ernest below. If using Python 2:

```
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]), np.arange(sorted_data.size+1)/float(sorted_data.size))
```

Comment: Divide by the size of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to overly complicate things, just divide by the number of data you have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some fake data:
data = np.random.randn(1000)

sorted_data = np.sort(data)  # Or data.sort(), if data can be modified

# Cumulative counts:
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]),
         np.arange(sorted_data.size+1)/sorted_data.size)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In the question you asked for the cumulative fraction. So I answered that question.

Comment: plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]),
         np.arange(sorted_data.size+1)/float(sorted_data.size)) fixed

Comment: I can use any version you like and I strongly doubt it has to do with the version of matplotlib. So you are apparently using python 2; since that is slowly getting old, best mention that fact whenever asking for help, so people can know about it

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could use min-max scaling by subtracting your values from the minimum and dividing by the difference between the max and min values.

```
y = np.arange(sorted_data.size+1)
# Using min-max scaling
y = (y - np.min(y)) / (np.max(y) - np.min(y))
```

Since the minimum of `y` in this case is 0, that's the same as dividing by the maximum of your y-values.

```
plt.step(np.concatenate([sorted_data, sorted_data[[-1]]]),
     y / np.max(y))
```

Comment: `max(np.arange(sorted_data.size+1)) ==  sorted_data.size`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest haha, totally blew right past that. Nice catch.