# Non-default argument follows default argument while defining a function

Tags: python, error-handling, histogram, cumulative-sum

This code is from
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408371/cumulative-distribution-plots-python)

```
def cumhist(df, bins=None, title, labels, range = None):
    '''Plot cumulative sum  + Histogram in one plot'''
    if bins==None:
       bins=int(df.YearDeci.max())-int(df.YearDeci.min())
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
    ax = plt.axes()
    plt.ylabel("Proportion")
    values, base, _ = plt.hist( df  , bins = bins, normed=True, alpha = 0.5, color = "green", range = range, label = "Histogram")
    ax_bis = ax.twinx()
    values = np.append(values,0)
    ax_bis.plot( base, np.cumsum(values)/ np.cumsum(values)[-1], color='darkorange', marker='o', linestyle='-', markersize = 1, label = "Cumulative Histogram" )
    plt.xlabel(labels)
    plt.ylabel("Proportion")
    plt.title(title)
    ax_bis.legend();
    ax.legend();
    plt.show()
    return
```

I only added the `If` part.
I am getting n error saying

```
  File "<ipython-input-80-07c703baab76>", line 1
    def cumhist(df, bins=None, title, labels, range = None):
               ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: The question you link to already explains exactly this. But I could not find any code resembling the code in your question.

Comment: oops wrong link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means you can't have `bins=None` before non-optional arguments in the list of arguments to the function. Either make `bins` non-optional by removing the default `=None` or move it to a position after the mandatory arguments.